# How to change a legend in the Superset Chart

Tags: apache-superset

I have a line graph like this but I couldn't figure out how to change the legend here. I tried to modify the metadata and couldn't make it work:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Count(*)` is a metric name, you need to go to your `datasource >edit>list metrics` and add a `verbose_name` with the kind of name you want to see on the legend and save. That should affect what is displayed on the legend. 
Please note that this true only if the legend is metric.When it's grouped, the legend is dictated by the group by field data.

Comment: **if count(*) is a metric name**, what if it is not?

Comment: The likely scenario is that it would be a list item from a `group by` field which means you would need to rename your list name to reflect the appropriate name.

Answer (score 15):

You can click the pencil icon next to My Metric and you can enter the new name you’d like to display.

[image: Edit names of metrics]